# Как скрыть FAB?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

В своем приложении сделал что по нажатию на floating action button выходит боковая шторка с меню. При выборе пункта меню вызывается свой фрагмент. Но кнопка FAB висит поверх фрагмента. Как скрыть FAB за фрагмент? Использую стандартный макет студии со шторкой.

Код фрагмента:

```
 package com.deize.deitaxi02.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.deize.deitaxi02.R;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentHome.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentHome#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentHome() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentHome.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentHome newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentHome fragment = new FragmentHome();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

 /*   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    } */

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

   View view;
 //  FloatingActionButton fab=view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.hide();

}
```

Comment: А может можно как то сделать что-бы фрагмент был выше кнопки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все предельно просто

```
floating_btn.hide()
```

Comment: View view;
   FloatingActionButton fab=view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
   fab.hide();                           добавлял этот код в класс фрагмента, студия ругается на hide(), не знает что это

Comment: покажите это в коде, где вы это делаете?

Comment: Попробуйте  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

Comment: А может можно как то сделать что-бы фрагмент был выше кнопки?

Comment: можно, но это надо в разметке менять

Answer (score 0):

если просто скрыть, то можно как любое View

```
floating_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Comment: Ругается, у класса fab нет такого метода